# Songs on iPhone I never put there

Tags: iphone, music

There are song on my iPhone that i never put there.
Only the playlist iPhone and Purchased are activated and those songs are not on that list.
And somehow, I can't remove them.
Anybody help?

Comment: Do you have iTunes Match enabled? Do you sync your iPhone with your computer sometimes?

Answer (score 1):

Look for a little cloud icon to the right of the song name... That mean's it's iTunes match. I had a bunch of songs I would never have gotten on my phone that kept coming up in genius shuffles. Turning off iTunes match did the trick.

Comment: I have the same problem and don't have iTunes Match enabled.